# matplotlib: clearing the scatter data before redrawing

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot, over an imshow (map).
I want a click event to add a new scatter point, which I have done by scater(newx,newy)).  The trouble is, I then want to add the ability to remove points using a pick event.  As there is no remove(pickX,PickY) function, I must get the picked Index and remove them from the list, which means I can't create my scatter as above, I must scatter(allx, ally).

So the bottom line is I need a method of removing the scatter plot and redrawing it with new data, without changing the presence of my imshow.  I have tried and tried:
just one attempt.

```
 fig = Figure()
 axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
 axes2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
 axes.imshow(map)
 axes2.scatter(allx,ally)
 # and the redraw
 fig.delaxes(axes2)
 axes2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
 axes2.scatter(NewscatterpointsX,NewscatterpointsY,picker=5)
 canvas.draw()
```

much to my suprise, this dispensed with my imshow and axes too :(.
Any methods of achieving my dream is much appreciated.
Andrew

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should have a good read of the [events docs here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/event_handling.html).

You can attach a function which gets called whenever the mouse is clicked. If you maintain a list of artists (points in this case) which can be picked, then you can ask if the mouse click event was inside the artists, and call the artist's `remove` method. If not, you can create a new artist, and add it to the list of clickable points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

pickable_artists = []
pt, = ax.plot(0.5, 0.5, 'o')  # 5 points tolerance
pickable_artists.append(pt)


def onclick(event):
    if event.inaxes is not None and not hasattr(event, 'already_picked'):
        ax = event.inaxes

        remove = [artist for artist in pickable_artists if artist.contains(event)[0]]

        if not remove:
            # add a pt
            x, y = ax.transData.inverted().transform_point([event.x, event.y])
            pt, = ax.plot(x, y, 'o', picker=5)
            pickable_artists.append(pt)
        else:
            for artist in remove:
                artist.remove()
        plt.draw()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Hope this helps you achieve your dream. :-)