# Unable to redraw the matplot inside Qt application

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt4, pyside

I want to call `draw()` method of [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/), which is used to update a figure that has been altered but not atomically re-drawn. Please note that the plot has been built inside QT application. Below is the error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 389, in process
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 227, in __call__
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
  File "matplotlib_qt.py", line 43, in mouseClick
    self.myMplCanvas.fig.draw()
TypeError: draw_wrapper() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

In standalone matplotlib application, the draw method can easily be called as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
# plot here and change plot variables later
# now re-draw it
plt.draw()
```

Below is the complete QT application code:

```
import sys
from matplotlib.backends import qt_compat
use_pyside = qt_compat.QT_API == qt_compat.QT_API_PYSIDE
if use_pyside:
    from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
else:
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        img = mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')
        lum_img = img[:, :, 0]
        self.axes.imshow(lum_img)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

class ApplicationWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setWindowTitle("application main window")

        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        self.myMplCanvas = MyMplCanvas(self.main_widget, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        l.addWidget(self.myMplCanvas)
        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.myMplCanvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.mouseClick)

    def mouseClick(self, event):
        self.myMplCanvas.fig.draw()


qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
aw = ApplicationWindow()
aw.setWindowTitle("hello")
aw.show()
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Whats going wrong here? Any workaround, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `plt.draw()` is not the same as `fig.draw()` if `fig` is a figure. In order to draw a figure a renderer needs to be supplied.

However, you probably want to draw the canvas instead of the figure.

```
fig.canvas.draw() # <- not recommended
# better:
fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

In the case of the question you already have the canvas as the `self.myMplCanvas`, hence you'd call

```
self.myMplCanvas.draw_idle()
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that draw() is not recommended. However, I am not even able to use it. Can you please provide more explanation. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are not able to use `fig.draw()`. The reason is that you would need to supply a renderer ( `fig.draw(renderer)`). However, you don't want to get a renderer and instead draw the canvas. `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` is recommended over `fig.canvas.draw()`. (For an explanation for this see first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43386513/4124317).)